# Java - JButton listener not triggering

Tags: java, swing, jframe, listener, jbutton

For a reason that I am not able to find , the SendListener is not working. 
    My Frame.class :
    http://pastebin.com/N28dFzYN
    My SendListener.class :
    http://pastebin.com/q75EVZtd

I dont get it. Everything else works just fine.

Comment: Code should be posted in the forum, not on another website. Also, the code should be posted in the form of a `SSCCE`. Search the web if you don't know what a SSCCE is.

Comment: Also avoid names that collide with related classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just don't add your listener to button. 
From line 119 in `Frame.java` you need to have:

```
//Console
sendCommand = new JButton("Send");
sendCommand.addActionListener(sender);
sendCommand.setVisible(true);
```